# Netbeans: folder is not downloading (sync) - symbolic link

Tags: file, netbeans, download, synchronization, symlink

I have an issue with NetBeans. I created a folder on my webserver with some files (pictures). Now I want to sync it with my project in NetBeans. While other folders had no problem, this folder is not been downloaded with the below mententioned summary.

For me it looks like the folder `xxx` (name changed) is seen as a symbolic link and thus it is not downloading. i checked the attributes (`chmod`) of the directory and it has the same settings as other folders.

1) How to check if this is realy a symbolic link? If I run `ls -la` I don't see differences to other folders.
2) How to change a symbolic link to a real folder?
3) How to sync the folder (if I cannot solve point 2)?    <-- I know that this is done generally by a right click ;-)

Thanks
Tim.

This is the result presented by NetBeans 8.2:

```
Summary
====================
Ignored:
dir       xxx                 File xxx is a symbolic link.
file      xxx/TNBild0.JPG     Some parent of file xxx/TNBild0.JPG is a symbolic link.
file      xxx/TNBild1.jpg     Some parent of file xxx/TNBild1.jpg is a symbolic link.
file      xxx/TNBild2.jpg     Some parent of file xxx/TNBild2.jpg is a symbolic link.
file      xxx/TNBild3.jpg     Some parent of file xxx/TNBild3.jpg is a symbolic link.
Runtime: 1 ms, processed: 0 file(s), 0 KB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not able to solve the above discribed issue, I deleted all local files and the project and created a brand new project which then finally downloaded all the files.

No good solution, but a workaround.